# When races are defeated, do the tokens all go back to the tray for redraw (if power allows)?

Tags: small-world

As an example, take the Pygmies.  "Each time you lose a Pygmy token, roll a reinforcement die and receive as many new Pygmies from storage tray as you rolled pips on the die (up to the number of Pygmies left)."

So if you lose a Pygmy, it goes back to the storage tray and then if you roll a 1 or more you can get it back?

Does this work that way for all races/powers?  they always go back to the storage tray (unless another rule says otherwise) and are available for any power/gift that brings them back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. From the rules on conquering regions in the base game, on what to do if you have been conquered:

> Permanently discard one Race token
>   **back into the Storage
>   tray**

And from the rules for Sorcerers, for example"

> with one of
>   your own **taken from the storage tray**.

Answer (score 2):

When a territory containing a player's active race is conquered, one of the tokens goes back to the tray and that player gets back the rest of them.

That does mean that they could potentially come back via special powers. Of course, it doesn't really matter which of your tokens the special power gives you, and so if the race has plenty of extra tokens (like the Skeletons or Sorcerers), in practice it'll often be a moot point. It matters more for races like the Mudmen, which can easily run out of tokens.

For completeness, from the base game rules on conquering:

> If Race tokens of another player occupied the Region prior
>   to its conquest, that player must immediately take all of these
>   Race tokens back in hand and:
>
> - Permanently discard one Race token back into the Storage
>     tray;
> - Keep the other Race tokens in hand, and redeploy them
>     in any other Region(s) still occupied by his race (if any) as
>     the final action of the current player's turn.

Comment: I don't agree on it being a moot point. The number of available Skeleton and Sorcerer tokens is purposefully limited so that you can run out. If killed tokens were removed from the game instead, those races would be less powerful.

Comment: @GendoIkari I've seen plenty of games with those races and I've never seen them get close to running out of tokens. It seems like the opponents would have to be playing incredibly poorly to let that happen, and by the time someone managed to get all the tokens out of the tray they'd already be winning so completely that the limited number of tokens wouldn't change anything.

Comment: Mudmen might be a better example, they're constantly running up against their token limit.

Comment: @bwarner Thanks, I haven't played Underground yet, that is indeed a good example. Edited to hopefully make everyone happy!

Comment: @Jefromi just because you haven't seen it happen doesn't mean that it doesn't happen. I have almost run out of skeletons before, and if they were permanently removed from the game I absolutely would have ran out of skeletons. The only reason why I didn't is because of the fact that killed skeletons return to the tray.

Comment: @Nick The answer says "in practice it'll often be a moot point"; your rare counterexample doesn't really change that. And I stand by what I said in the comment: if you're able to go through all the tokens in the tray, something unusual is going on. In the long run, it takes fewer tokens for your opponents to kill one of yours (by conquering one territory) than it does for you to regain one (by conquering *two* territories), so while you can certainly do well, your opponents should be able to keep you from running away with it. Doesn't mean it's impossible, just unlikely.

Comment: @Jefromi you're making my point for me and you don't even realize it. Sure, it is easier for someone to kill 1 skeleton than it is for you to regain 1 skeleton. But that 1 skeleton that they kill goes into the tray, so under normal circumstances you will never run out of skeletons because you can keep recycling them. If they were removed from the game you would max out on skeleton tokens pretty quick, which means it is not a moot point.

Comment: @Nick Nonetheless, there are always at least 9 extra skeleton tokens in the tray to start, so if you were removing the killed ones from the game, you'd have to conquer 20 nonempty regions in order to be affected by the limit. And that's not going to happen "pretty quick", for the reasons I mentioned, unless people are not attacking you much and leaving only one token in territories adjacent to yours (not usually great for them), or you're keeping the skeletons through most of the game and/or abandoning territories in order to conquer new ones (not usually great for you).